# How to change the onPress behavior of the support toolbar menu items?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I use the new ToolBar from the support package.

On Android 5.0 I get a nice ripple effect on touch. 
On lower versions I also get a pressed state but it is very subtle.

How do I change the pressed state of a menu item for the toolbar?

Comment: put `<item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/some_selector</item>` inside your style/theme normaly it is `android\support\v7\appcompat\res\drawable\abc_item_background_holo_(light/dark).xml`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the pressed state effect in your style with

```
    <item name="selectableItemBackground">
        @drawable/selectable_item_background_selector
    </item>

    <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">
        @drawable/selectable_item_background_selector
    </item>
```

On Android 5.0 you can override the style in "style-v21" and set a ripple drawable (in drawable-v21):

```
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">
        @drawable/ripple_selector
    </item>
```

To change the pressed state style only for the toolbar you can set a custom theme

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      app:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
      android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```